# Display data from Postgres in Angular app. CORS issue

Tags: angular, postgresql, express, proxy, cors

I am new learner and I want to display the information for users (in Postgres database) in Angular app. What I have is: 
Database (table Users):

```
    id |   name   | age |  username   
-------+----------+----+---------------
     1 | P        | 38  | user1
     2 | Q        | 38  | user2
     3 | R        | 38  | user3
```

Angular project:
server.ts:

```
const express = require('express'),
      cors = require('cors'),
      pg = require("pg");

const app = express();

const config = {
    user: 'appuser',
    database: 'users',
    password: '12345',
    port: 5432
  };

const pool = new pg.Pool(config);

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    pool.connect(function (err, client, done) {
        if (err) {
            done();
            console.log("Can not connect to the DB" + err);
        }
        client.query('SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY id', function (err, 
result) { 
            done();
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(400).send(err);
            }
            //res.status(200).send(result.rows[0]);
            return res.status(200).json(result.rows);
        })
    })
 });

app.listen(4000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running.. on Port 4000');
});
```

user.ts:

```
export interface User {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    age: number;
    username: string;
}
```

user.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse  } from 
'@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { User } from './user';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
};
const apiUrl = "http://localhost:4200/api";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class UserService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUsers (): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(apiUrl)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError('getUser', [])));
  }

  getUser(id: number): Observable<User> {
    const url = `${apiUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<User>(apiUrl).pipe(
      tap(_ => console.log(`fetched User id=${id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<User>(`getUser id=${id}`))
    );
  }
}
```

user.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../user';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  users: User[];
constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();
}

getUsers(): void {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(
    users => this.users = users);
  }
```

user.component.html:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>UserName</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
          <td>{{user.id}}</td>
          </a>
          <td>{{user.name}}</td>
          <td>{{user.age}}</td>
          <td>{{user.username}}</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

proxy.conf.json:

```
{
"/api": {
  "target": "http://localhost:4000",
  "secure": false,
  "pathRewrite": {
    "^/api": ""
  }
}
```

package.json:

```
...
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
...
```

When runing "node server.ts" I can see the data in http://localhost:4000, also when I "ng serve -o" my angular app is running and there are no errors, but there is no data in the table. Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you look in your browser console for errors? I suspect your angular app is served from a different port then your service in which case your service will need to return the correct CORS headers. BTW the *ngFor should be on your tr tag, a table has one body with many rows.

Comment: You are right, there is an error : "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4000/users' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."
I tried to enable CORS (https://github.com/expressjs/cors ) in the server.ts file, but    I couldn't solve the issue. What should I do?

Comment: Update the server.ts in your question to reflect what you changed to try to get cors working. Best to try the Simple usage example first thought it would be unsafe for production use. Also update your question including the title to reflect that this is a CORS problem.

Comment: You've put `origin: 'https://localhost:4200'`in cors configuration in `server.ts`. Change `https` to `http`.

Comment: Also, if your end goal is to serve both the app and the REST api from the same server, configure ne serve to act as a reverse proxy, and you won't need CORS anymore. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

Comment: Thank you everyone, I used proxy. I edited my code, now it's working.